# Perron-Frobenius theorem to positive delay differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, eigenvalues, spectral-radius, perrons-formula

The Perron-Frobenius theorem is that the largest eigenvalue (in modulus) of a non-negative matrix is real (and simple) and corresponds to a non-negative eigenvector. It is applicable to the positive linear system $\dot{x}(t) = A x(t)$, where A is a Metzler matrix. In detail, the spectral radius of this linear system is real and corresponds to a non-negative eigenvector.

I really wonder whether it is also true for the positive delay-differential equations $\dot{x}(t) = A x(t) + B x(t-\tau)$, where A is a Metzler matrix, B is a non-negative matrix, $\tau>0$ is a constant delay. I tried to look for this matter in MathSciNet and Science-direct but could not find any reference. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot.